# Grab HTML Table Data

Tags: java, html

Is it possible that I can get data from a table in my HTML website using another website ( javascript ) or a java program?

for example

I have a table named

Students

```
ID NAME
1   Carlo
```

**UPDATE**

I want to make a code in java that reads an html website and get some data to it.

Comment: You mean JavaScript I presume

Comment: wait I'll edit my post

Comment: I already update my question. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) to read an analyze web sites. It can also handle javascript on web sites.

You can search the html tag you want by e.g. `id` or xpath. Or you follow the html hirarchical structure of the page

Answer (score 1):

```
you can also use HTML Parsers linke [jsoup][1] to get the details of table

public static void getTableDetails()
{
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("url").get();

    for (Element table : doc.select("table[name="students")) 
    {

     for (Element row : table.select("tr)")) {
        Elements tds = row.select("td");
       System.out.println(tds.get(0).text() + "->" + tds.get(1).text());
     }
}
```

in  the for loops change the values and place according to your requirements